# How to Delete a Specific Line in a Text File?

Tags: c#, winforms, io

I have a little problem. Let me explain the workplace.

My Text File Structure:
X_OFFSET 0
Y_OFFSET 0
IDSTART
0001 222 222 222 222
0002 250 500 250
0003 1700 500 500 250
0004 900 600 500 250
0005 1350 250 500 250
IDEND

What I must do is to find the IDSTART-IDEND block and DELETE a spesific line between them.

Example: User set id1 123 124 125 126 => id1 means ID, 123 means Center X, 124 means Center Y, 125 means Center Z and 126 means Radius.

Workplace:
The user will enter the id number(such as id5) to a text box, then click a button to delete the whole line starting with "id5"...

is this possible? if it is, How can I make it?

[Improved_v2]

Okey, I've made some changes and it works now. But, there is problem.

FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\hucre.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader okuma = new StreamReader(fs); 
        string Metin = okuma.ReadToEnd(); 
        char[] Ayrac = { '\n' };
        MetinSplit = Metin.Split(Ayrac);

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MetinSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        GeciciDizi.Add("a");
        GeciciDizi2.Add("b");
    }
    // MetinSplit'i GeciciDiziye At.
    for (int i = 0; i < MetinSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        GeciciDizi[i] = MetinSplit[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MetinSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        GeciciDizi2[i] = MetinSplit[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < GeciciDizi.Count; i++)
    {
        if((string)GeciciDizi[i]==SilinecekDeger)
            GeciciDizi.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < GeciciDizi.Count; i++)
    {
        GeciciDizi2[i] = GeciciDizi[i];
    }

    okuma.Close(); 
    fs.Close();
    FileStream newFile = new FileStream("C:\\hucretemp.txt",      FileMode.Open);

    StreamWriter yaz = new StreamWriter(newFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < GeciciDizi2.Count; i++)
    {
        yaz.WriteLine(GeciciDizi2[i]);
    }

    yaz.Close();
    yeniFile.Close();
    File.Delete("C:\\hucre.txt");

    File.Move(@"C:\\hucretemp.txt",   @"C:\\hucre.txt");
}
```

}

Here, the problem is this.

When I read from the file hucre.txt to my tempArrayList, it wrtes to array like this below.

X_OFFSET 0\r\n
Y_OFFSET 0\r\n
IDSTART\r\n
0001 222 222 222 222\r\n
0002 250 500 250\r\n
0003 1700 500 500 250\r\n
0004 900 600 500 250\r\n
0005 1350 250 500 250\r\n
IDEND

**it adds one more \r.**

So, when I want to read something from the "hucre.txt",
I can't managed to do it, because
it becomes like this 0001 222 222 222 222**\r\r\n**

How can I remove it?

I really am desperate, please help :/

My best regards...

Comment: "it didn't work" is a poor problem description. What didn't happen? What did happen? Errors? Exceptions?

Comment: This is a very poor quality question, you should not expect people here to debug large blocks of code. Have you tried following yoru code in the debugger? Do you get an exception? Have you tried to simplify your code to locate the problem?

Comment: I've changed the question. May be you can now have a look at it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't read through all your code, but your I/O logic is way to complicated and inefficient.

Basic idea:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(orgFileName))
using (var writer = File.CreateText(tmpFileName))
{
    while (true)
    {
       string line = reader.ReadLine();
       if (line == null)
         break; // done

       // logic to analyze / track content

       if ( Is_special_line)
       {
          // do something, or maybe nothing (skip)
       }
       else
       {
          writer.WriteLine(line);
       }
    }
}

File.Delete(orgFilename);
File.Rename(tmpFilename, orgFilename);
```